# Issues in posting JS variable to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery, post

I'm trying to post a JS variable to a PHP script but I'm not able to do it. Here are the scripts,

The following JS is embedded in a script named "check.php",

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content-area').mouseup(function() {
 var selection = getSelected();
  if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
     alert('Sending the following text to the server via AJAX: ' + selection);
            $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url : 'calculate.php',
             data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection)  
            });
     }
   });
   });  
</script>
```

I'm posting the "selection" variable using ajax to
The PHP script(calculate.php) where I'm receiving the value as follows.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
      strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' &&  
      $selection = trim($_POST['selection'])) {
        $selText = $selection;
       }
?>
```

I'm getting a null value at the server-side i.e "calculate.php". Please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once.

in ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url : 'calculate.php',
            data: { selection : selection},
          });
```

In calculate.php get your data using `$_POST['selection'];`

Comment: I checked it using if(isset($_POST['selection']) in calculate.php, and the data is not received at the server side. But it shows the alert msg on selecting the text. Pl help

Comment: Why post an answer with same content/proposal as other already posted answer? If it didn't worked for that answer, why it should works for yours?

Answer (score 1):

Change you `data` attribute to:

```
data: { selection: encodeURI(selection) }
```

Then it will be available on your PHP script as:

```
$_POST['selection']
```

Further, look at your if condition in your PHP script:

```
$selection = trim($_POST['selection'])
```

If you're want to compare those values, I think you should use `==`. If not, just move it outside the condition.

Comment: Still no success. Still getting null value. Do you have any other fix?

Comment: Even the updated thing is not working. Also I checked it using if(isset($_POST['selection']) in calculate.php, and the data is not received at the server side. But it shows the alert msg on selecting the text. I'm disheartened, Pl help

Comment: @mario23 is hard to help you with that lack of information. Post the result of `print_r($_POST);` at the beggining of your PHP script and your request from [developers tools(Chrome)](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) - it can be a screenshot or even request header text...